# Can we setup .Net Development environment in a GCP VM instance

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform

I have GCP free account. I have created ASP.Net Framework based windows Virtual Machine instance. How to set it up for .Net application development by installing VS 2017. 
OR always i should have development set up in my local machine??

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud only offers Windows Server versions on VM instances. Microsoft requires licensing of Windows Server (paid licensing).

The only size VM instance that is part of the free tier is the f1-micro instance. This instance only has 600 MB of memory which is too small to run Windows Server. The disk size is 10 GB, which is borderline to install Windows and Visual Studio meaning you should pick a much bigger disk which then costs more.

Microsoft requires license fees to run Windows Server.

You need an upgraded account (paid) to run Windows Server.

Given the above, it is a personal choice where to run your development environment. Personal desktops make great choices for Visual Studio due to high processor and sequential disk performance, multiple high resolution monitors, etc. Running in the cloud offers high network bandwidth speeds, a variety of compute sizes, disk snapshots, tight integration with Google Cloud, security, etc.